# Access items in list pertaining to GroupBy() item

Tags: c#, list, foreach, ienumerable, observablecollection

I am instantiating a `List`, derived from an `ObservableCollection`:

```
var paidTrips = PaidTrips
    .GroupBy(p => new {p.LicenseHolderID})
    .ToList();
```

Which, through a `foreach` loop, gives me access to the various distinct values in `LicenseHolderID`.

```
foreach (var licenseHolder in paidTrips) {
    // accessing the string value of LicenseHolderID
    // but no access to the other items
}
```

**What I need help with:**

How can I obtain access to the other items in `paidTrips`, which pertain to `LicenseHolderID`? (*Why: I am creating invoices, one per `LicenseHolderID`, and I am building the invoice with the data from all the other collection properties*).

To give some context, here's the full collection I am working with:

```
PaidTrips.Add(new PaidTrip {

    LicenseHolderID = dr[0].ToString(),
    VehicleID = dr[1].ToString(),
    Year = dr[2].ToString(),
    Month = dr[3].ToString(),
    Payment = (decimal)dr[4],
    PaymentNet = (decimal)dr[5],
    OrderFee = (decimal)dr[6],
    PaymentFee = (decimal)dr[7],
    TripVATcode = (decimal)dr[8],
    LicenseHolderInvoiceID = dr[9].ToString(),
    TripFeeNet = (decimal)dr[10],
    TripFeeVATcode = (decimal)dr[11],
    RidelRegionInvoiceID = dr[12].ToString(),
});
```

Comment: Its not very clear what you are trying to achieve. What do you mean by "obtain access to the other items in that collection"? Which collection are you referring to?

Comment: For reference `.GroupBy()` in C# returns an object which groups list of items by a key. So for example if you want to access all the "PaidTrip" items for a specific `licenseHolderID` you could either say for `paidTrips.Where(w => w.Key == licenseHolderID)` or just not do the grouping and have `PaidTrips.Where(w => w.licenseHolderID == licenseHolderID)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It does depend what your looking to do with the data for each invoice?  are you looking to summarise the data within each LicenseHolderID group?

```
var PaidTrips = new List<PaidTrip>();

var paidTrips = PaidTrips
    .GroupBy(p => new { p.LicenseHolderID })
    .ToList();

foreach (var group in paidTrips)
{
    var licenseHolderID = group.Key.LicenseHolderID;
    
    //ie here total payment (This sums all payments for this LicenseHolderID)
    var totalPayment = group.Sum(x => x.Payment)

   // count of payments made (This Counts all Payments greater than 0)
   var totalPayments = group.Count(x => x.Payment > 0)

   //Use variables in your invoice generation
  
}
```

or as above iterate through each group item and access it in singular form.

Comment: You came to my rescue again, brother - thanks a bunch!
This did the trick for me. Making my week a lot easier.
Yes, I do actually need the sum for all the `Payment`, among others. But I also need the sum for each row. How would I access that? (If this begs a new question, let me know -- I'll create one)

Comment: One group contains multiple rows with the same LicenseHolderID,   Each Row has multiple components.   The .Sum method is used to sum one attribute across multiple rows.  In this case based on one LicenseHolderID.    You can add two summed results together or if you require per row basis you'll need to nest another foreach loop inside which iterates through each row.   ie foreach(var innerGroup in group)

Comment: I appreciate your continued help. Let's say I want to get all the `Payment` rows out as an array (I am guessing, using the ToArray extension method, that I can later sort through, how would that look like? `foreach (var innerGroup in group) { decimal payment = group.ToArray /* what goes here*/ }`

Comment: If you wanted to select the "attribute" Payment from one of the group iterations you can use a select method.  i.e var paymentArray = group.Select(x => x.Payment).ToList();   This would result in a list of values for that particular LicenseHolderID Key of the group in iteration.

Comment: Superb! Ok, last question. How would I then extract and separate each of the items in that new list we just created?

Comment: I did var `var payment= innerGroup.Select(x => x.Payment).ToList();`
`decimal _payment = payment.First();`
but not sure how to output all the other values.

Comment: If you nested an innerGroup within group you should only have one value for Payment.  The innerGroup Variable should be one object of Paid Trip.   Where each of the properties can be accessed like so,  innerGroup.Payment or innerGroup.PaymentNet.   If you want to get the list of Payment attribute from the group based on LicenseHolderID then run it in the outer group.  Like from the answer above however just add var paymentsReturned = group.Select(x => x.Payment).ToList();  each item value could be accessed using a for loop and index. i.e. var valueFound = paymentsReturned[0] or foreach loop

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly, you want to access each group member's property. To achieve this, you should use nested foreach to traverse each group and access its members.

```
    var PaidTrips = new List<PaidTrip>();

    var paidTrips = PaidTrips
        .GroupBy(p => new { p.LicenseHolderID })
        .ToList();

    foreach (var group in paidTrips)
    {
        var licenseHolderID = group.Key.LicenseHolderID;

        foreach (var paidTrip in group.ToList())
        {
            Console.WriteLine(paidTrip.TripFeeNet);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
foreach (var licenseHolder in paidTrips) {
    // accessing the string value of LicenseHolderID
    if (licenseHolder.Key == desiredLicenseHolderID){
       foreach (var paidItem in licenseHolder){
          paidItem.VehicleID = .......
       }
    }        
}
```

The `.GrouBy()` Returns a [IGrouping](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.igrouping-2?view=net-5.0) object which contains the Key and the elements grouped by the key. To access the elements of the Key grouping you are after once you iterated through the items and found the one, you can simply iterate through the item as an array.